# Mongodb $nin php Not Working

Tags: php, mongodb

This shows me everything (including 55d9d86746ba9a3a7f642b83).
I don't want it to show me the data in the array `$veri`.

```
$veri=Array
(
    [0] => 55d9d86746ba9a3a7f642b83
)

$urun = $c->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)));
```

Comment: Looks like a "string" to me. Try casting to [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven can u explain in code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongo->selectDB("foo");

    $cur = $db->bar;
    $veri = array(
        new MongoId('55d9d86746ba9a3a7f642b83')
    );

    $urun = $cur->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)));

    foreach($urun as $doc) {
        var_dump($doc);
    }

 ?>
```

Notice how I use `MongoId`, instead of just copy pasting the id as is. Also notice that the array doesn't need an index `[0]`